# Search Events and News via Calendar Portlet

Tags: plone

Event items are searchable in Plone's default calendar portlet. When clicking on a date when an event occurs, it uses `search?review_state=published&start.query:record:list:date...` to look for events. How can I add News Item, or even custom types to be searchable in calendar portlet?

Comment: News Items don't have the start and end dates required for that query to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ZMI there's a tool portal_calendar:

```
http://<localhost>:8080/plone/portal_calendar/manage_configure
```

In the `configure` tab there's a select list where you can specify any content type to be shown. The only condition is that they have to provide start & end attributes that return DateTime.